# Restangular functions not working in ng-repeat child

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I'm using Restangular in my AngularJS app to comunicate with the backend API. The styling isn't really top-notch yet in the example below, but since my question isn't html-related, that doesn't matter. My problem is that the `change_status()` function (and the other functions) works only with the parent (`todo`), but not with the child (`child`). So calling `change_status(todo)` will work perfectly, but calling `change_status(child)` will give me a `todo.put is not a function` error. I don't get this: passing in the parent should yield the exact same result as passing in the child, as both are similar objects (see example JSON).

I can't really provide a working example, since this error depends on communication with an API. I have, however, included all the relevant code below:

HTML:

```
...
<tbody ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter:search" ng-hide="todo.hidden">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:100px" ng-click="change_status(todo)">
            <span ng-if="todo.done" class="label label-success">Done</span>
            <span ng-if="!todo.done" class="label label-warning">In Progress</span>
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="child in todo.children | filter:search" ng-hide="child.hidden">
        <td style="width:100px" ng-click="change_status(child)">
            <span ng-if="child.done" class="label label-success">Done</span>
            <span ng-if="!child.done" class="label label-warning">In Progress</span>
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
...
```

CONTROLLER:

```
...
$scope.change_status = function(todo) {
        todo.done = !todo.done;
        todo.put();
        $rootScope.todos = api.all('todo').getList().$object;
    };
...
```

EXAMPLE JSON (used in the ng-repeat):

```
[
  {
    "description": null,
    "title": "Learn to make a great todo-app using AngularJS",
    "children": [
      {
        "description": null,
        "title": "Learn AngularJS",
        "children" : [],
        "done": false,
        "user": 1,
        "hidden": false,
        "id": 2
      }
    ],
    "done": false,
    "user": 1,
    "hidden": false,
    "id": 1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Children is a normal array, is not restangularized, so you don't have restangular methods, you'll have to restangularize it (check restangularizeCollection method) to be able to use it for restangular methods (put).
The parent array is already restangularized as it is the one you retrieve through restangular call.

Comment: How would I do this without having to restangularize every child manually?

Comment: Could u retrieve the children as a second restangular call, sort of nested rest call from parent todo?

Comment: That would become really messy, because I've got some deeply nested children (my JSON example was simplified). If I had to call all of the children manually, my code would become extremely messy and unmaintainable.

Comment: It shouldn't really, right now you have child in todo.children, ok, so instead of looking in todo.children, you should use todo.getChildren or something similar that will be a function returning a restangular call to retrieve the children of todo (something like todo.getList(children)). Also that would load only what you need to load on demand instead of loading all information at once.

Comment: Anyway, I am probably overcomplicating things here, you only have one resource, right? That will bring the whole hierarchy of todos, so, it is much simpler, just execute the put method always on top level, that should update also children.

Comment: I needed all resources at once, and since I had a custom API output, I couldn't always simply update the top-model, since the lower models weren't 'officially' queried in the first place. It would have taken quite a bit of unnecessary data usage as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the customPUT method, which didn't require me to Restangularize all my objects (which would have been really hard to do):

```
Restangular.allUrl('edittodo/' + todo.id).customPUT(todo)
```